# Java.lang.classnotfoundException While Creating custom keyboard

Tags: java, android

I want to create a custom keyboard in android.I folllowed the following tutorial for that :-
http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-custom-keyboard-on-android--cms-22615

the tutorial has no activity class only service class.When I run the code .It is giving me the classnotfound exception  as follows :-

```
08-23 06:14:41.627: E/AndroidRuntime(645):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:2570)
08-23 06:14:41.627: E/AndroidRuntime(645):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1800(ActivityThread.java:139)
08-23 06:14:41.627: E/AndroidRuntime(645):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1292)
08-23 06:14:41.627: E/AndroidRuntime(645):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
08-23 06:14:41.627: E/AndroidRuntime(645):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
08-23 06:14:41.627: E/AndroidRuntime(645):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5086)
08-23 06:14:41.627: E/AndroidRuntime(645):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-23 06:14:41.627: E/AndroidRuntime(645):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
08-23 06:14:41.627: E/AndroidRuntime(645):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
08-23 06:14:41.627: E/AndroidRuntime(645):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
08-23 06:14:41.627: E/AndroidRuntime(645):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-23 06:14:41.627: E/AndroidRuntime(645): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.kb.SimpleIME" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.kb-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.example.kb-2, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
08-23 06:14:41.627: E/AndroidRuntime(645):  at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
08-23 06:14:41.627: E/AndroidRuntime(645):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
08-23 06:14:41.627: E/AndroidRuntime(645):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
08-23 06:14:41.627: E/AndroidRuntime(645):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:2567)
08-23 06:14:41.627: E/AndroidRuntime(645):  ... 10 more
```

My mainfest file as foloows :-

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.kb"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <service
        android:name=".SimpleIME"
        android:label="@string/simple_ime"
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_INPUT_METHOD" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.view.im"
            android:resource="@xml/method" />

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.view.InputMethod" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
</application>
```

It has only one java class as follows :-

```
package kb;

import com.example.kb.R;

import android.inputmethodservice.InputMethodService;
import android.inputmethodservice.Keyboard;
import android.inputmethodservice.KeyboardView;
import android.inputmethodservice.KeyboardView.OnKeyboardActionListener;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputConnection;

public class SimpleIME extends InputMethodService implements
        OnKeyboardActionListener {

    private KeyboardView kv;
    private Keyboard keyboard;

    private boolean caps = false;

    @Override
    public View onCreateInputView() {
        kv = (KeyboardView) getLayoutInflater()
                .inflate(R.layout.keyboard, null);
        keyboard = new Keyboard(this, R.xml.qwerty);
        kv.setKeyboard(keyboard);
        kv.setOnKeyboardActionListener(this);
        return kv;
    }

    private void playClick(int keyCode) {
        AudioManager am = (AudioManager) getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);
        switch (keyCode) {
        case 32:
            am.playSoundEffect(AudioManager.FX_KEYPRESS_SPACEBAR);
            break;
        case Keyboard.KEYCODE_DONE:
        case 10:
            am.playSoundEffect(AudioManager.FX_KEYPRESS_RETURN);
            break;
        case Keyboard.KEYCODE_DELETE:
            am.playSoundEffect(AudioManager.FX_KEYPRESS_DELETE);
            break;
        default:
            am.playSoundEffect(AudioManager.FX_KEYPRESS_STANDARD);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onKey(int primaryCode, int[] keyCodes) {

        InputConnection ic = getCurrentInputConnection();
        playClick(primaryCode);
        switch (primaryCode) {
        case Keyboard.KEYCODE_DELETE:
            ic.deleteSurroundingText(1, 0);
            break;
        case Keyboard.KEYCODE_SHIFT:
            caps = !caps;
            keyboard.setShifted(caps);
            kv.invalidateAllKeys();
            break;
        case Keyboard.KEYCODE_DONE:
            ic.sendKeyEvent(new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN,
                    KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER));
            break;
        default:
            char code = (char) primaryCode;
            if (Character.isLetter(code) && caps) {
                code = Character.toUpperCase(code);
            }
            ic.commitText(String.valueOf(code), 1);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onPress(int primaryCode) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onRelease(int primaryCode) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onText(CharSequence text) {
    }

    @Override
    public void swipeDown() {
    }

    @Override
    public void swipeLeft() {
    }

    @Override
    public void swipeRight() 
    }

    @Override
    public void swipeUp() {
    }
}
```

I have  serached all over the place but didn't find the solution.One solution is to check the name of class(SimpleIME) with the mainfest declaration name(.SimpleIME) Which is same .Please help me with this problem.I have found nowhere the solution.

Comment: Looking at the top of your `SimpleIME` class the package declaration only lists `kb`, whereas looking at what the classloader is trying to load it should be `com.example.kb`. As such, are you sure that your `SimpleIME` class is in the correct package?

Comment: Wow you are genius .I just deleted the default package which was made as kb. and created a new one with name 'com.example.kb'.It is working fine..thanks a lot